# Can I publish a library to multiple npm registries at the same time?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish, github-package-registry

I created one repository and library. And I want to publish to npm registry and github package at the same time.
Do you know an easy way to do this?

I am currently publishing this with a change. It would be great if this could be solved with a simple setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can achieve it with [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) or [bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit) .

Both two libraries allow you to manage multiple packages on the same repo (monorepo). **lerna** is absolutely free and **bit** will have paid plan if you working on a commercial project.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but you can achieve this using GitHub Actions. Refer to [this workflow file](https://github.com/ClydeDz/horoscope-npm/blob/main/.github/workflows/npm_lib.yaml#L46-L63) where I'm publishing my npm package to the npm js registry and also to the GitHub registry.